# Data is saved in a Combobox instead of being actualised

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I hope you can help me with my little problem here..

My file consists 3 worksheets. 
1. data
2. report
3. helping worksheet to make some calculations

When I open the file, I click on a button to implement a calculation, which starts some requests. This request first copies the data from worksheet 1 (data) to worksheet 3 (helping worksheet). After further requests, all done in userforms, the data in worksheet 3 is filtered for the requested data. The userform gets its data from worksheet 3 and is shown in a combobox via scritping dictionary.

Here's the problem:

My data is contained on three spreadsheets.
If I hit the button on worksheet 2, the requests do their work on the first time. If I want to do it again (click the button again to implement copying, filter and calculation), the filter is set wrong and so is the calculation. 
But, if worksheet 3 is opened (the current view is on worksheet 3, not worksheet 2, where the button is) and I start the requests and calculation manually in the editor window, the filter and calculation is always correct.

I think the error is when the combobox generates the dictionary respectively gets its data and applies a filter. The filter is always the one which was set at the first requests. With further requests the filter doesn't change, it is still the filter from the first request.
Maybe there should be some kind of reset after doing the requests and calculation?

I used the following code for the userform/combobox/scritping dictionary:

```
 Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Taking the data from the helping working sheet

    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim lngZ As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Sheets("helpsheet")

    For i = 12 To Sheets("helpsheet").Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    If Sheets("helpsheet").Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
    ComboBox2.AddItem .Cells(i, 3)
    objDic(.Cells(i, 3).Value) = 0
    End If

    Next

    End With

    Me.ComboBox2.List = objDic.keys

    With Me.ComboBox2
    .AddItem "all areas"
    End With

End Sub
```

I really hope somebody can help me as I can't proceed :(

Thanks

Rafa

Answer (score 1):

It's better to activate/select the source sheet first before executing the filter and copying data on/from that sheet.

Sure, people say that one shouldn't use `Sheets("SheetName").select` in one's code, but as long as it solves my error, I'd do it:).

So, try to put this `Sheets("YourSource").select` before executing your code. If you want to go back to your Sheet 2 (where the button is), just use `Sheets("Sheet2Name").select`.

Hope I could help!

Answer (score 0):

if you always use full range reference you shouldn't meet any issue

my guessing is that in your other (not shown) code you're:

- making some sheet activation/selection that makes a "bad environment" for the 2nd start
- using not fully referenced range variables

you may want to show the other code to help us help you

BTW you can refactor the `UserForm_Initialize` code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim i As Long

    Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Sheets("helpsheet")
        For i = 12 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
            If Not .Rows(i).Hidden Then objDic(.Cells(i, 3).Value) = 0
        Next
    End With

    With Me.ComboBox2
        .List = objDic.keys
        .AddItem "all areas"
    End With
End Sub
```

or, to shorten it down a little more:

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each cell In Sheets("helpsheet").Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        objDic(cell.Value) = 0
    Next cell

    With Me.ComboBox2
        .List = objDic.keys
        .AddItem "all areas"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it is super simple..

To reset the comboboxes you just have to add END before END SUB. This way everything gets to its initial state without any values or properties.

I did not activate or select the worksheet because I don't want anybody to see what is behind it. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: using `END` is highly discouraged! Try my solution instead